# How to view the To-Do-Bar in Outlook for Mac?

Tags: macos, ms-office, microsoft

I am new to Apple and I have Outlook 2016 installed in my Mac. I am unable to see the To-Do-Bar which I use in Outlook for Windows.

How do I view the To-Do-Bar in Outlook for Mac?

Comment: Even though the code that builds Outlook for Mac and iOS and windows is unified, the features are certainly not comparable at this point. There are many tings you'll only be able to do on the windows client for quite some time would be my guess.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose this is documented by the choice of words:

[Outlook for PC](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-and-customize-the-to-do-bar-4b6c5bb4-88a0-46c2-9159-6d0a0133ff79?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) - Use and customize the To-Do bar

That view isn't present on Outlook 2016 version 16.13 or less for macOS.

You'll need to run on windows or try the webmail app. If you search "to do bar" in the help for Outlook - you'll find you can't even put things in to the ribbon yet and there's a link to request it on some web site.

In the mean time, you'll likely need to open a couple main windows and look over your tasks and calendar.